# Infer type based on the closest prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am hoping someone can help me out or clarify if what I am trying to achieve is possible. I am currently creating a component but is having trouble with regard to type inference. Here's the code below.

```
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import * as React from "react";

type StringOrNumber = number | string;

type Offset = {
  top?: StringOrNumber;
  left?: StringOrNumber;
  right?: StringOrNumber;
  bottom?: StringOrNumber;
};

type Tab<T extends unknown[]> = {
  label: string;
  items: T;
  render: (item: T[number]) => JSX.Element | null;
  badgeCount?: StringOrNumber;
};

type NotificationProps<T extends Tab<unknown[]>[]> = {
  tabs?: T;
  offset?: Offset;
  heading?: string;
  onMarkAllUsRead?(): void;
};

export default function Notification<T extends Tab<unknown[]>[]>(
  props: NotificationProps<T>,
) {
  return <div>{props.heading}</div>;
}

// Example usage:
<Notification
  offset={{
    top: "50px",
  }}
  tabs={[
    {
      label: "Users",
      items: new Array(5).fill(null).map(() => ({
        name: faker.name.fullName(),
        email: faker.internet.email(),
      })),
      render: (user) => {
        return null;
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Emails",
      items: new Array(5).fill(null).map(() => ({
        type: faker.random.word(),
        body: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
      })),
      render: (email) => {
        return null;
      },
    },
  ]}
/>;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the params in `render` infer the type of the closest `items` but currently it is of type `unknown`. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Most React questions concerning generic prop types are really just questions about normal functions. You can reduce your minimal example to just [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4bnaN), and remove Faker or React from the code.

Comment: Closest I've gotten infers the item types instead of the tabs themselves: https://tsplay.dev/Navrnm But it still says the render parameter is implicitly `any`...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation, but all I want to say is that, you are getting that implicit any error because you constrained your generic array as unknown[], which means its items can be of any type.
If you did something like this:

```
type Tab<T extends number[]> = {
   label: string;
   items: T;
   render: (item: T[number]) => string | null;
   badgeCount?: string | number;
};
```

typescript would know that every item in T array is a number. This is very simplified example, but just so you can point out your mistake.

This is my [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-imnfzr?file=/src/Notification.tsx).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The component should be *generic*. It should allow other things besides `MyArrayType`. Also, the types of `user` and `email` in the `render` function aren't the right type.

Comment: As I said I wanted to comment but low reputation :/